# jQuery submit in contact form

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have a problem with browser compatibility. Script works fine (sends email, changes the form after submit to the text) on Firefox and Chrome.

The problem comes with Safari and IE browsers. After clicking submit the page goes to the top, the form doesn't change in to the success message but it sends the email.

Full code of contact form: http://pastebin.com/mAUNMHFe

I believe the problem is here:

```
$(function () {
    $('#contact').validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                url: 'process.php',
                success: function () {
                    $('#contact').hide();
                    $('#contact-form').append("<p class='thanks'>Thanks!</p>")
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to `return false` from the `submitHandler` method

Comment: i was reading about 
 $("a").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
thou i didn't succeed to put it in the code to work :|

Comment: Did you add `return false` and tried?

Comment: no, i am reading about it now and i will try to put it in the code.

edit: should it just go 
$('#contact-form').append("<p class='thanks'>Thanks!</p>")
return false; ?
edit2: no that didn't worked, goes to the top of the page even on firefox.